# Convert .tar.gz to sequence file after splitting tar.gz

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, compression, hadoop2

Is it possible to convert 1 .tar.gz file to 1 sequence file using map reduce ?
So far came across all solutions that are doing this without splitting tar.gz or from local file system.

http://qethanm.cc/projects/forqlift/examples/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Imagine your gzip-compressed file stored in HDFS whose size is 1 GB. With an HDFS block size of
64 MB, the file will be stored as 16 blocks. However, creating a split for each block won’t
work since it is impossible to start reading at an arbitrary point in the gzip stream, and
therefore impossible for a map task to read its split independently of the others. The
gzip format uses DEFLATE to store the compressed data, and DEFLATE stores data
as a series of compressed blocks. The problem is that the start of each block is not
distinguished in any way that would allow a reader positioned at an arbitrary point in
the stream to advance to the beginning of the next block, thereby synchronizing itself
with the stream. For this reason, gzip does not support splitting.

Comment: I found this link on processing of. gz which has used CombineFIleSplit - http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/bd-hadoopcombine/.. It seems to gunzip during runtime and create parts out of the file ready to consume by MR

Comment: I read through link more closely and is probably not splitting but instead combining multiple gzip , article contains 1000 gzip which is total to 56 MB. I have extremely big gz on the other hand - 5  GB each

Comment: This seems like only possible alternative - if I split 5 GB .tar.gz into 128 MB proper tar.gz-parts then each Mapper will get a block of data to work on without splitting instead of whole file. Related : http://www.informatik-vollmer.de/software/split-tar.php